# После торможение wheele collider застревает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему после полной остановки "машины", когда я снова задаю *AddForce*, "машина" отказывается ехать?

Ссылка на видео [тык](https://yadi.sk/i/QaLkfVY90hcK5w)

Я думаю, что проблема в *Wheele Collider*, поиграл со значениями, но бестолку.

> Хавнокод

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class StriderController: MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;

    [SerializeField]
    [Range(-200.0f, 500.0f)]
    private float _speed = 0;

    [SerializeField]
    private int _braking = 750;

    [SerializeField]
    private bool _brake = false;


    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        VelocityController(_speed, _braking);
    }

    private void VelocityController(float speed, int braking)
    {
        if (_brake)
        {
            rb.AddForce(-rb.velocity * braking);
            _speed = 0;
        }

        if (speed != 0)
        {
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 100 * speed);
        }
     
    }

}
```

Comment: а ты переприсваиваешь значение _speed после "полной остановки"?

Comment: Когда включён "тормоз", _speed всегда равен 0, иначе будет дёргаться (одновременно AddForce на движение и торможение работает если не ставить _speed на 0). Когда "тормоз" выключен, _speed я заново присваиваю. Ощущение как-будто колёса застревают в террейне, когда приподнимаю машину, она снова едет.

Comment: я не вижу переприсваивания переменной _speed. но если там ломается само тело(падает в текстуры), то пока не понимаю как помочь

Comment: вот видео [хорясь](https://yadi.sk/d/obcaxVYNdVU6XA)

Comment: В коде нету переписывание, в менеджере есть бегунок.
атрибут
`[Range(-200.0f, 500.0f)]`